# JPA select from ManyToMany, how?

Tags: java, jpa

I have `User` class and `BattleReportILogItem` class.
This class (`User`, `BattleReportILogItem`) are `@Entity`.

I don't know, how to write a code for select from this `Entity`.

I want select `setOfBattleLogs` from class `BattleReportILogItem`.

`User` have **0..N** `BattleReportILogItem`

**USER:**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = DomainConstant.TABLE_USER)
    public class User implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @Column(name = DomainConstant.DOMAIN_USER_ID)
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long userId;

        @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
        @JoinTable(name = DomainConstant.VIEW_USER_BATTLE_LOGS, joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = DomainConstant.DOMAIN_USER_ID)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = DomainConstant.DOMAIN_BATTLE_REPORT_ID)})
        private Set<BattleReportILogItem> setOfBattleLogs = new HashSet<>();

....(other stuff, get and set methods...)
```

**BattleReportILogItem**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = DomainConstant.TABLE_BATTLE_REPORT)
public class BattleReportILogItem implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = DomainConstant.DOMAIN_BATTLE_REPORT_ID)
    private Long BattleReportILogItemId;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "setOfBattleLogs")
    private Set<User> setOfBattleLogs = new HashSet<>();

    ....(other stuff, get and set methods...)
```

**My try**:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select c1 \n"
        + "from User c1 \n"
        + "join c1.setOfBattleLogs c2 \n"
        + "where c1.userId = :c1userId", User.class);
```

... so, this code is wrong, I know... :-(

Can you some body help me? I read some thread on this stackoverflow site, but it doen't help me the solve my problem.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so, this code is wrong, I know

No it's not *that* wrong, what makes you think it is?

You just need to select c2 instead of c1:

```
//I'll rename c1 to u and c2 to b to reduce confusion in the query
select b from User u join u.setOfBattleLogs b where u.userId = :paramUserId
```

Of course you'd then not get a list of `User` entities but a list of `BattleReportILogItem` entities.

Btw, in your `BattleReportILogItem` class you have `private Set<User> setOfBattleLogs = new HashSet<>();` - I assume the set should be named `users` or something similar instead.

You could also swap the entities in the query:

```
select b from BattleReportILogItem b join b.users u where u.userId = :paramUserId
```

Comment: Dear Thomas, thank you for your help and clear answer! Work nice. I will acept your replye after 4 minutes.